# FoundationPress Couldn't delete file: Failure in sftp

Tags: php, wordpress, ssh, zurb-foundation, sftp

So I've began doing development for a WP site and have started doing the development on my local machine and then transferring my work over through a sftp to a separate server. For the theme development I tried using FoundationPress for the front-end framework for creating a theme. I worked with it for a day and then decided that it wasn't exactly what I wanted and now Im trying to remove it from the sftp `public_html/foo/wp-content/themes/bar`

Instead though it returns me the `Couldn't delete file: Failure` message.
I think it has something to do with how FoundationPress requires node.js, bower, and grunt installs for it to work. All the `.php` files are removed from the directory but the bower_components and node_modules remain so it won't let me remove the directory completely.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File dependencies will not affect deleting files through SFTP. They are just files, they don't know know who depends on who. Are you using a sftp client?

Do you have SSH accesss to this server? That's another way to manage your files. You can run (very carefully) the command:

```
rm -rf directory-you-want-to-delete/
```

r = recursively for everything inside the directory including all directories within it

f = force, meaning don't ask me if I am sure

I say very carefully because this command will not ask you 'Are you sure?', it will delete EVERYTHING if you don't know what you are doing. If you run `rm -rf /`, you will erase your entire server partition.

Comment: I do have ssh access. So if I run that command it should delete everything in the directory I specify?

Comment: Yep, considering you have the privileges. Here is a wiki on the rm command:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rm_%28Unix%29

Comment: Great that worked @umagrama. Do you know why it wouldn't let me do it at first? I guess I was only running the `rmdir specific/path` command through the sftp shell and not the ssh.

Comment: Great to hear! About not working through FTP, are you sure those directories were empty? rmdir won't delete them if they are not empty.